# ValueError: The future belongs to a different loop than the one specified as the loop argument

Tags: python, asynchronous, python-asyncio

Im trying to run a simple loop Using python asyncio and the ensure_future function , i've created the event , set the loop , but when I'm trying to run all tasks I get a ValueError :

```
 ValueError: The future belongs to a different loop than the one specified as the loop argument
```

Here is the code im trying to execute ..

```
for account_item in accounts:
    account_obj_map[account_item.id] = account_item
    balance_params = {"account-id": account_item.id}
    balance_request = GetBalanceService(balance_params).get_request(**self.__kwargs)
    balance_url = server_url + balance_request.url
    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
    tasks.append(asyncio.ensure_future(
        self.async_get_account_balance(balance_url,account_item.id,account_balance_json_map)))

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

# the Error was occur when running the loop (line below)
loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.wait(tasks))
```

Any help will be much appriciated !!

Comment: You call `asyncio.new_event_loop()` on every iteration of the loop?

Comment: ohh god , my bad.. moving the new_event_loop() above the for loop solved my problem .. Thanks !